# Is there any way to edit the page layouts for standard objects in a Salesforce sandbox?

Tags: page-layout, sandbox, standard-objects, pagelayoutassignment

I am trying to create different page layouts for specific record types and when I assign these layouts to the record types, under the objects assignment, no changes happen. It seems that there is a "phantom" page layout that all the standard objects point to in the sandbox as the view I see when creating a new record does not even resemble the default layout assigned. I have tried to use the cli to push xml changes to the layout and that does not work either. It seems the standard objects in a sandbox are pointing to page layouts that are not easily found. Is there any way to edit the page layouts for standard objects in a Salesforce sandbox and actually see a visual change? Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Hi Jarod. There is no difference here between sandbox and production orgs. Are you sure you are using 'classic' page layouts and not Lightning Record Pages for this object?

Comment: Hi Guy, yes I am using standard page layouts. What is confusing is that the standard page layout that is currently assigned, does not resemble what is being shown when you create or edit a record, and applying changes to the layout do not affect what is displayed at all.

Comment: perhaps you have dynamic Lightning Pages that can completely ignore the page layout definition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your object probably has a Lightning Record Page activated where the UI would be customized.

Either that or you need to verify the layout assignment with regards to the user profile and the record type.